# Syntax danger: Token '}' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 35 of the expression [yourSelectRadio={item.Polarisation}]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

```
error : Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax danger: Token '}' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 35 of the expression [yourSelectRadio={item.Polarisation}] starting at [}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$parse/syntax?p0=%7D&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=35&p3=yourSelectRadio%3D%7Bitem.Polarisation%7D&p4=%7D
```

my code:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-init="yourSelectRadio={item.Polarisation}"> 
<label class="btn btn-success ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="yourSelectRadio" btn-radio="'Vertical'">Vertical</label> 
<label class="btn btn-success ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="yourSelectRadio" btn-radio="'Horizontal'">Horizontal</label>
</div>
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: `yourSelectRadio={item.Polarisation}` isn't valid javascript.

Comment: ... make it valid. Given that invalid javascript, I have no idea what your intention was, therefore i can't suggest how to "fix it"

Answer (score 3):

{} is an object you need a key for the item

```
{ 'key' : item.Polarisation } ?
```

or

```
yourSelectRadio=item.Polarisation // if it is an object
```

**edit** :

the `ng-init` function requires an object. JSON is defined as 
`{ "key" : "value" }` not `{ [OBJECT] }`

assuming `item.Polarisation ~= { "thing" : "one", "otherthing" : 2 }`

There are two ways to fix the error.

Direct assignment

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-init="yourSelectRadio=item.Polarisation">
```

*-or-*

Encapsulation

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-init="yourSelectRadio={'radioItem': item.Polarisation}">
```

Comment: Thanks @KevinB , the quotes were so he wouldn't confuse the key with the item object hes referencing.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Can you write out a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

use angular.toJson(Object) :

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-init="yourSelectRadio=angular.toJson(item.Polarisation)"> 
        <label class="btn btn-success ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="yourSelectRadio" btn-radio="'Vertical'">Vertical</label> 
        <label class="btn btn-success ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="yourSelectRadio" btn-radio="'Horizontal'">Horizontal</label>
</div>
```